# Calculate sum of linecost in POLINE with automation script in IBM Maximo

Tags: python, maximo

I'm new in scriptin and just start to learn that.

I need a script that will do next:

Script must enter sum value in my new field in POLINE. I have sql code for what I want:

select sum(linecost) from poline
group by itemnum.

So every time when I create new PO, in new field must enter sum value of linecost of one item. so if I use some item few times in different PO I need to check sum of linecost is used for this item.

Thank you very much

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure to read some of our articles before asking something! [How do i ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest finding and taking introductory online tutorials or classes in both Java and Python. Then, you can look up [Maximo V7.6.0.9 JavaDoc](https://developer.ibm.com/assetmanagement/developer-resources/apis-and-sdks/) and study psdi.server.MXServer and psdi.mbo.Mbo.

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion. I already started  taking tutorials. I just ask this because I need this in my work, and only solution that I see is scripting.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programmers to help each other solve programming problems. What you have is a business requirement, not a programming problem. Your question got downvoted (by someone else) because it feels like you're asking us to do your job of satisfying the requirement instead of telling us what you have tried and the problem you are running into. Read [ask], as @William suggested on your question, and provide a [example] and we would love to upvote your question and provide helpful answers.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your comment.  I'm going to that.